# Python Redis times out every 2 minutes

Tags: python, redis

I have **Redis 3.5.3** installed from https://pypi.org/project/redis/
I wish to subscribe to certain callbacks which I can successfully receive using the following Python program:

```
import redis

def main():
    try:
        r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=26379, username='myusername', password='mypassword')

        p = r.pubsub()
        p.psubscribe('+sdown')
        p.psubscribe('-sdown')
        p.psubscribe('+switch-master')
        p.subscribe('+sentinel')

        while True:
            message = p.get_message()
            if message:
                print(message)

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)    <-- "Connection closed by server"
```

BUT after exactly 120 seconds I hit the exception with the error message **"Connection closed by server"**

How can I avoid this? is there a setting in any config file that I can change?

Or can I pass in any parameters to Redis?

I have redis instance running as follows:

```
ps -ef | grep redis
redis     1549     1  0 14:29 ?        00:00:06 /usr/sbin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
redis     5209     1  0 15:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/redis-sentinel *:26379 [sentinel]
```

Comment: Do you actually have an instance of redis running on localhost?

Comment: yes, see edit above

Answer (score 1):

You pointed redis at port 26379, but redis isn't running on that port- its running on 6379. You DO have sentinel running on 26379. You have two options-

1. Don't use Sentinel. If you're using localhost, you're already defeating the purpose anyway ;) The fix then is just changing the port number.
2. If you want to use it, you have to tell redis-py to do so, its not automatic.

The following code is from the section `Sentinel support` from the redis-py docs

```
from redis.sentinel import Sentinel
sentinel = Sentinel([('localhost', 26379)], socket_timeout=0.1)
master = sentinel.master_for('mymaster', socket_timeout=0.1)
slave = sentinel.slave_for('mymaster', socket_timeout=0.1)
master.set('foo', 'bar')
slave.get('foo')
```

Comment: i will try switching ports thanks. Why do you say I am defecting the purpose if I'm using localhost? And why do I get what looks like successful callbacks  for the +sdown for example when I bring a node offline?

Comment: I changed the port number, I do not get the timeout issue but I also do not receive any of the callbacks +sdown for example.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Redis Sentinel is an app to manage a cluster of redis instances, if you just have one running locally, its not helping you any. There are two reasons you may not be getting messages- 1. Is there anything _sending_ messages? From another process? If not- no messages. 2. Your pattern for `psubscribe` - I don't know what you were trying for, but I don't believe "+" is a valid character to start a regex pattern.